# ¿Decimal a formato hora en Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, vba

Estoy tratando de llevar a formato hora un numero decimal, pero tengo un problema, únicamente me muestra las horas, omitiendo minutos y segundos, ¿alguien tiene alguna forma de hacerlo diferente a esta?: la respuesta del siguiente código es el siguiente: 08:00:00 siendo la respuesta correcta 08:20:00

Creo que un error podría ser que la división no arroje el número de decimales preciso, pero no tengo idea como solucionarlo :c

```
    Dim hora As Decimal = 100000 / 12000
    Dim d As Date = Date.FromOADate(hora)
    tHoras.Text = d.TimeOfDay.ToString
```

Comment: Hola. A mí `Format((100000 / 12000)/24,"hh:nn:ss")` me devuelve `08:20:00` por si te sirve.Cuando quiero pasar de decimal a formato hora, hago un cambio de base dividiendo entre 24. Y más que con `Decimal`, suelo usar como tipo de datos `Double` cuando trabajo con tiempos. Espero que te pueda servir.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, si me funcionó!

Comment: Estupendo, lo publico como respuesta para que la marques y así cerramos la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mí `Format((100000 / 12000)/24,"hh:nn:ss")` me devuelve `08:20:00` por si te sirve.Cuando quiero pasar de decimal a formato hora, hago un cambio de base dividiendo entre 24. Y más que con `Decimal`, suelo usar como tipo de datos `Double` cuando trabajo con tiempos. Espero que te pueda servir